# Trying to access array offset on value of type bool (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm Learning Laravel and I'm trying to show details of an item but I get this ErrorException

my controller

```
    public function show($request)
    {
        $request = DriverRequest::find($request);
        // dd($request);
        return view ('driverDashboard.showRequestDetails',['request' => $request]);
        // return view ('driverDashboard.showRequestDetails',['requests' => $request]);
    }
```

my foreach

```
@foreach ($request as $request) 
            <div class="body txt-c d-flex p-20 mt-20 mb-20 block-mobile">
              <div>
                {{ $request ['name'] }}</td>
              </div>
              <div>
                {{ $request ['budget'] }}</td>
              </div>
              <div>
                {{ $request ['status'] }}</td>
              </div>
            </div>
@endforeach
```

here are my ErrorException

Comment: `$request as $request` looks peculiar to me.

Answer (score 1):

`::find()` only returns a single `DriverRequest` object, or `null`. There is no need for the `foreach()` at all; just do `$request->name`, `$request->budget`, etc.

Also, `$request` is a bad variable name; that should only be used for the global `Request` object in Laravel, like `public function example(Request $request)`, or similar.

Change your code as follows:

```
public function show($id) {
  $driverRequest = DriverRequest::findOrFail($id);

  return view ('driverDashboard.showRequestDetails', ['driverRequest' => $driverRequest]);
}
```

Then in your `showRequestDetails.blade.php`:

```
<div class="body txt-c d-flex p-20 mt-20 mb-20 block-mobile">
  <div>
    {{ $driverRequest->name }}</td>
  </div>
  <div>
    {{ $driverRequest->budget }}</td>
  </div>
  <div>
    {{ $driverRequest->status }}</td>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: still have exception
"Attempt to read property "name" on bool"

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75890162/edit) to show your new code. The code I posted has no Booleans...